# Authentication using JWT for systems(client_id) and users (username, password)

Tags: api, authentication, delphi, jwt, token

**TL;DR:**

- We need JWT Auth on an API that is customers specific
- Each customer has an API.dll in their own application pool and site on IIS
- We need 3rd party BI solutions to be able to securely call the API
- We need single users from the customer database to be able to call the API with their existing username and password

**Details**

At my job we have created a somewhat simple rest API we need authentication for.
The thing is, that the API is not shared between customers. So each customer gets a DLL that is set up to read/write to individual databases.

We would like our API to be usable by 3rdparty systems that our customers use, e.g. BI solutions - as well as user login (the specific users of our system).

**Current setup**

- Each customer has their own: database, application pool, site, desktop app and api.dll (running on IIS)
- Customers are free to create any number of users in our desktop application and grant these users varying rights. These users are not centralized across customers. So we have no information about a customers created users (unless we look in their database)
- If the customer is self hosted they control the API and the authentication on their server.
- If we host their solution we create an active directory user for that customers API and enable basic authentication for that site, granting permission for that single user.

**Question**

*How can auth be set up for this somewhat weird situation, allowing single user authentication as well as allowing 3rd party integrations?*

As I understand from my reading we need some kind of hybrid between `grant_type: password` and `grant_type:client_credentials`.

As with anything job related, time is a huge factor, but I want the solution to adhere to standards and best practices as closely as possible.

Comment: You're implicitly referring to OAuth2. Why would you need OAuth2?

Comment: @Olivier I'm not experienced in authorization, but would like the service to be generic so we can use the authorization model for other services as well. I am unsure what other standards exists for this task

Comment: Why don't you just use basic authentication? It's hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: @Olivier We are developing HR software. When an employee is terminated or has updated salary information through the API, it is crucial that we know which user did this. With basic auth we only know which WINDOWS user started the API process, but not which useraccount from our system changed the data.

Comment: Basic auth has nothing to do with Windows users. You can send whatever credentials you like.